# How to apply an Android device as a MIDI controller for LMMS on Ubuntu?

Tags: midi, daw, usb, android

I've just started fiddling around with LMMS on Ubuntu Linux. I don't want to buy hardware yet but would like to play instruments and samples with an external MIDI controller rather than with the Piano Roll.

Hoped, I could use my Android (6.0) tablet with an appropriate app for that. So I installed TouchDAW (free version), plugged the tablet via USB into my laptop and activated the "MIDI" option from the upper Android pull menu.

In LMMS, I picked the "MIDI input" and "MIDI output" options for the instrument track in concern. While the LMMS interface recognized my Android device as potential MIDI device, I could not make it actually work. In TouchDAW on the tablet I took the Keyboard view, but the pressed keys would not be recognized in LMMS on the Ubuntu laptop.

How can I use my Android device as a (simple) MIDI controller / keyboard with LMMS on Ubuntu?

`lsusb` zeigt:

```
lsusb 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f3:21d5 Elan Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 011: ID 2a47:90ba  
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1bcf:2b95 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

`aseqdump` zeigt:

```
 aseqdump -l
 Port    Client name                      Port name
  0:0    System                           Timer
  0:1    System                           Announce
 14:0    Midi Through                     Midi Through Port-0
 20:0    Aquaris X5 Plus                  Aquaris X5 Plus MIDI 1
128:1    LMMS                             piano02.ogg
```

Comment: Does the Android device appear in the output of `lsusb` amd `aseqdump -l`?

Comment: Added the outputs to my question

Comment: If you run `aseqdump -p Aquaris`, do you get any events?

Comment: Meanwhile, I've also tried a second Android device (Smartphone, Android 7.1.1). While I can connect the latter via USB to my laptop and also choose MIDI via USB in TouchDAW, I can't choose MIDI via USB on the first device (tablet, Android 6.0). Even if USB-MIDI is active, the app says it was not available or used in another process - which it isn't of course. Consequently, `aseqdump -p Aquaris` does not show events with the tablet while it shows events when the phone is plugged in. But, it plays notes not on keyboard keys but when I press any control keys ...